# Student many to many causing error on updating of record

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Ok This makes more since now. I am having an issue at the web api side now in that the student is trying to be readded.

```
public Booking AddBooking(Booking booking)
{            
  db.AddBooking(booking);
  return booking;
}
```

U will see here on the button click am checking for the said student.

```
private async void btnBookStudent_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    var test = Helpers.Dates.GetDateZeroTime(selectedBookingDate.Date).Add(timePicker.Time);
    var student = await api.GetStudentById(StudentId);


    var newBooking = new Booking
    {
        IsAbsent = false,
        IsActive = true,
        IsDeleted = false,
        Time = Helpers.Dates.GetDateZeroTime(selectedBookingDate.Date).Add(timePicker.Time),
        DayOfWeek = DayNumber


    };
    newBooking.Students = new List<Student>();
    if (StudentId != 0)//here am checking if the student exists or not
    {
        student = await api.GetStudentById(StudentId);
        newBooking.Students.Add(student);
    }
    api.AddToBooking(newBooking);
    await DisplayAlert(Constants.AppName, "Booking Created For Student", "OK");

}
```

But the error I am still getting is

> Message: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
> 'Student' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Because on my wepapi side im just simply adding booking.

```
public Booking AddBooking(Booking booking)
{          
    db.AddBooking(booking);
    return booking;
}
```

Surely since i already found the student in previous step the api controller should be fine and just interpt student as being an update yes the student was found during debugging.

Comment: You get the student once at the top of the application - why are you getting it again inside the if statement? And your error message indicates you are setting the ID of the student manually - you should not set the ID manually and allow the DB to create one.

Comment: Am not setting it manually

Comment: @csharpdude77 if you already get the student, then alert are you trying to add again?

Comment: So is the ID of the student the default value (0 if int, null if string)? If not, you will need to set it to 0 or null as the DB will have to decide on the ID

Comment: The error is complaining about the fact that the student being inserted into the booking already has an ID while the student ID is an identity column which cannot be set by you unless you override it

Comment: The issues is that although the json is sending the right and correct student Id at the database side the Add is messing up fixed now but wasnt your reason